# Insertar 'N' veces de registros con los mismos Input

Tags: php, html, mysql

Buenos Dias tengo un formulario donde los input se generan automáticamente con un for dependiendo de un numero asignado. En pocas palabras un formulario de 4 campos se genera n veces para ser guardada información para el mismo id.

El problema es que los input se generan con el mismo "name" y eso hace que al mandarlos a insertar solo se guarden una fila

La pregunta es como se le hace para meterlos a un arreglo y cambiarles el nombre al "name" del input para que se guarden los n numeros de inputs en una sola consulta

```
<?php  
    $cantidadI=3;
 ?>
<div id="contenedor">
    <form id="datos" action="inserta.php" method="post">
        <div id="tabla">
            <table>
                <?php for ($i=0; $i<=$cantidad; $i++) { 

                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" align="center">
                        Nombre:<input id="nombre" type="text" name="nombre[]" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" align="center">
                        No Fase:<input id="nofase" type="text" name="nofase[]" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" align="center">
                        Dias Duracion:<input id="diasdu" type="text" name="diasdu[]" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" align="center">
                        Precio:<input id="presio" type="text" name="presio[]" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            </table><br>
            </div>

        <input id="guarda" type="submit" value="Guardar" />
        <a href="#"><input id="cance" type="button" value="Cancelar" /></a>
    </form>
</div>
```

INSERT:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $values) {
$query = "INSERT INTO detalles(nombre, no_fase, dias_duracion, precio) VALUES ('".$values['nombre']."','".$values['nofase']."','".$values['diasdu']."','".$values['presio']."')";
mysql_query($query, $conexion);
}
```

Al hacer el print_r($_POST) me doy cuenta que solo toma

```
Array ( [nombre] => Array ( [0] => miguel [1] => miguel [2] => miguel ) [nofase] => Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 7 [2] => 7 ) [diasdu] => Array ( [0] => 45 [1] => 45 [2] => 45 ) [presio] => Array ( [0] => 1236 [1] => 1236 [2] => 1236 ) )
```

Comment: Hola Laura, bienvenida a StackOverflow, podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar el código que tienes hasta este momento?

Comment: Si claro ayer vi un ejemplo que resolviste en otra pregunta, y supongo que es parecido pero el otro ejemplo generaba los inputs , y yo ya los tengo por default es la diferencia. Deja agrego el codigo

Comment: Laura porque no subís el código completo de como quedó el insert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una opción es crear un array multidimensional con el `$i` que utilizas en el for:

```
        <?php for ($i=0; $i<=3 ; $i++) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" align="center">
                    Nombre:<input id="nombre" type="text" name="usuario[<?= $i ?>][nombre]" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" align="center">
                    No Fase:<input id="nofase" type="text" name="usuario[<?= $i ?>][nofase]" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" align="center">
                    Dias Duracion:<input id="diasdu" type="text" name="usuario[<?= $i ?>][diasdu]" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" align="center">
                    Precio:<input id="presio" type="text" name="usuario[<?= $i ?>][presio]" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
```

Tendrías que modificar un poco tu forma de hacer el INSERT en la base de datos también:

```
foreach ($_POST['usuario'] as $key => $values) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO detalles(nombre, no_fase, dias_duracion, precio) VALUES ('".$values['nombre']."','".$values['nofase']."','".$values['diasdu']."','".$values['presio']."')";
    mysql_query($query, $conexion);
}
```

Por cierto te recomiendo que **NO** uses mysql_query, utiliza las funciones de mysqli.

Comment: Creo que no esta leyendo los valores me salio este error 
Notice: Undefined offset: 0

y en la base de datos me registro 4 filas en 0 xD

Comment: Si manda los arreglos como debe de ser 
Array ( [usuario] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [nombre] => angel [nofase] => 12 [diasdu] => 36 [presio] => 54 ) [2] => Array ( [nombre] => juan [nofase] => 78 [diasdu] => 65 [presio] => 56 ) [3] => Array ( [nombre] => luis [nofase] => 96 [diasdu] => 65 [presio] => 45 ) ) )

Comment: Salio lo mismo u.u 
Notice: Undefined offset: 2

Comment: el foreach no esta funcionando no esta tomando los valores pero si hace el recorrido del array
INSERT INTO detalles(nombre,no_fase,dias_duracion,precio)VALUES('','','','')

Comment: Creo que ya funciono solo era cuestion de quitar el [$key] MUCHÍSIMAS GRASIAS te lo agradezco mucho

Answer (score 0):

Para poder llevar a cabo lo que solicitas, solo es necesario que le agregues a los inputs unos corchetes y con esto ya el envío de la info estará en array, es decir:

```
<input type="text" name="nombre[]" value="asdf" />
<input type="text" name="nombre[]" value="jkl" />
```